# Multiple IFs in same formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested, ifs

Please can someone help me combine the following:

1. If P20="1" and F27="" then the value should be 0.00
2. If P20="2" then, if B22 is greater than or equal to 1000:

   ```
   (B22-1000)*0.06+200
   ```

   but if B22 is less than 1000:

   ```
   B22*0.2
   ```
3. If P20="3" then:

   ```
   B22*F27*E3
   ```

The below bring back a value of FALSE

```
 =IF(AND(P20="1",F27=""),0,IF(P20="2",IFS(B22>1000,(B22-1000)*0.06+200,B22<1001,B22*0.2),IF(P20="3",B22*F27*E3)))
```

Comment: That second thing makes no sense: it should be: If P20="2" AND ... (and even then the last part is wrong).

Comment: Hi @Dominique, thank you for your comment. I've amended my question and the formula slightly but am now getting a 'FALSE' value. Please can you advise what is wrong. I can make each part of the formula work on its own but don't know how to combine them properly. I'm new to this and just learning as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(P20=1,F27=""),0,IF(P20=2,IF(B22>=1000,(B22-1000)*0.06+200,B22*0.2),IF(P20=3,B22*F27*E3)))
```

1. I dropped the `IFS`, because normal `IF` contains a `THEN` and an `ELSE` part.
2. I work with `P20=1` instead of `P20="1"`.
3. Not mentioned in the formula: I've modified "cell formatting" to "number".